# add record to the parent grid by selecting a row in the child grid using kendo

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How do i update the main(parent)grid by selecting a row in the child grid using kendo ui?I have a parent grid which uses local data to get populated and onlclick of add new record there is a tab grid.When i select a row in the child grid and then click on update the data must bind to the parent grid.I am able to retrieve the selected elements but not able to bind to the parent grid datasource.Kindly provide suggestions for the same.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Popup editing</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="css/examples-offline.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/userMaintenance.js"></script>
         <script src="../js/console.js"></script>
     <script>

        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
     <center><h2 style="color:blue;">User Maintenance</h2> </center>
    <!-- grid element -->
    <div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="grid" ></div>
    <script>
    var data = createRandomData(50);
     var main = [{Globalid:"fdsdf",UserName:"System Admin",SystemRole:"5",Title:"5"},
     {Globalid:"qwewqeqwe",UserName:"System Admin",SystemRole:"5",Title:"5"}
                          ];
                          var mylocaldatasource=new kendo.data.DataSource({
                          data:main
                          });


                          mylocaldatasource.read();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: data,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            Globalid: { type: "string" },
                            UserName: { type: "string" },
                            SystemRole: { type: "string" },
                            Title: { type: "string" }

                        }
                    }
                }

            },
            height: 430,
            pageable: false,
            editable: {
                mode: "popup",
                template: kendo.template($("#popup_editor").html())
            },

            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "Globalid",
                    title: "Global id"

                },
                {
                    field: "UserName",
                    title: "User Name"

                },
                {
                    field: "SystemRole",
                    title: "System Role"
                },
                 {
                    field: "Title",
                    title: "Title",
                    format: "{0:c}",
                    width: "100px"
                },
                {
                    command: ["edit", "Remove"],
                    title: "&nbsp;",
                    width: "160px"
                }
            ],
            edit: function(e){
                e.container.find(".nested-tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({});

                 e.container.find(".tabstrip-grid").kendoGrid({
                  dataSource: mylocaldatasource,
                pageable: false,
                selectable:true,
                              height: 300,
                           columns:[
                                    {
                                        field: "Globalid",
                                        title: "Global id"

                                    },
                                    {
                                        field: "UserName",
                                        title: "User Name"

                                    },
                                    {
                                        field: "SystemRole",
                                        title: "System Role"
                                    },
                                     {
                                        field: "Title",
                                        title: "Title",
                                        format: "{0:c}",
                                        width: "100px"
                                    }
                                ],
                                change:grid_change


                          });


                     }


        });
    function grid_change(e) {
        var selectedRows = this.select();
        var selectedDataItems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
          var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[i]);
          selectedDataItems.push(dataItem);
         // var globalid=this.dataItem(this.select()).Globalid;
          alert(this.dataItem(this.select()).Globalid);

        }
        // selectedDataItems contains all selected data items
      }
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");        
        grid.bind("change", grid_change);
         grid.dataSource.add({
           id:i+1,
          Globalid: this.dataItem(this.select()).Globalid,
          UserName: selectedDataItems.UserName,
          SystemRole: selectedDataItems.SystemRole,
          Title: selectedDataItems.Title
        });

    });

    </script>
    </div>



    <!-- popup editor template -->
    <script id="popup_editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
      <div class="nested-tabstrip">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Search
            </li>
            <li>
                Search Results
            </li> 
        </ul>
       <div>
            <div class="Search">      
        <div class="k-edit-label">
            <label for="Globalid">Global id:</label>
        </div>

            <div class="k-edit-field">  
                <input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="Globalid" data-bind="value:Globalid">
            </div>

            <div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="UserName">User Name: </label>
            </div>

            <div class="k-edit-field">
                <input name="UserName"
                    data-bind="value:UserName"
                    data-value-field="UserName"
                     />
            </div>

                <div class="k-edit-label">System Role: </div>
                    <div class="k-edit-field">
                    <select name="SystemRole" >
                      <option value="PAA User">PAA User</option>
                      <option value="PAA Admin">PAA Admin</option>
                      <option value="Executive">Executive</option>
                      <option value="System Admin">System Admin</option>
                     </select>
                </div>

         <div class="k-edit-label">
            <label for="Title">Title:</label>
         </div>
        <div class="k-edit-field">
            <input type="text" name="Title" data-bind="value:Title"  />
         </div> 
     </div> 
     </div> 
    <div>
            <div class="tabstrip-grid" id="childgrid"></div> 
        </div> 



    </div>




    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this where you define the child Grid.

```
$("#ChildGrid tbody tr").on("click", function (e) {
    var grid = $("#ChildGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select())
    window.parent.CallFromChild(dataItem);
});
```

At the main grid create this function:

```
function CallFromChild(dataItemFromChild){
    var parentGrid = $("#ParentGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var parentDataItem = parentGrid.dataItem.set("ColumnName",dataItemFromChild.Value);
}
```

You can try something like this. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the input but this doesnt seem to work,Probably because the child grid is a tab grid and in fact it is present in the pop up window.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle example?